# Launch IE from a C++ program

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

I have a program written in C++ which does some computer diagnostics. Before the  program exits, I need it to launch Internet Explorer and navigate to a specific URL. How do I do that from C++?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you are... I am assuming that you're talking MSVC++ here...

```
// I do not recommend this... but will work for you
system("\"%ProgramFiles%\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\"");


// I would use this instead... give users what they want
#include <windows.h>

void main()
{
     ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982266/launch-ie-from-a-c-program", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

Comment: this will launch the default browser, and that might be IE?

Comment: Thank you, but that launches the default browser which might not be IE.

Comment: Are you using some custom plug-in or something?  I'd !%$%$ if a program opened up anything other than Firefox for me.  Users have a choice these days ;)

Comment: There you are... I added a way for Internet Explorer, though, I didn't like doing it, lol.

Comment: Indeed. This is for an employer to validate an employee's machine. IE is required.

Comment: Another way to get path is from registry, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE, default value is the path to the executable.

Answer (score 3):

if you really need to launch internet explorer you should also look into using CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, ...) and then navigating. depending on what else you want to do it might be a better option.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to launch IE or just some content in a browser? The `ShellExecute` function will launch whatever browser is configured to be the default. Call it like this:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", szURL, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: Do not use the desktop window as the parent. If you do not wish to have a parent, pass `NULL`. I've updated the code here; if you use this in any of your own programs, you should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

```
include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  ShellExecute(0, "open",
                  "C:\\progra~1\\intern~1\\iexplore.exe",
                  "http://www.foo.com",
                  "",
                  SW_MAXIMIZE); 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using just standard C++, if iexplore is on the path then

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...
string foo ("iexplore.exe http://example.com");
system(foo.c_str());
```

If it's not on the path then you need to work out the path somehow and pass the whole thing to the system call.

```
string foo ("path\\to\\iexplore.exe http://example.com");
system(foo.c_str());
```

Comment: See my post above... you should either use genenv, or %ProgramFiles%

Comment: +1  This answer is better than mine.  Expect that iexplore.exe is on the path (when would it not be?) and call generically with system()

Comment: annoyingly, iexplore isn't on my PATH on XP. :-(

Comment: This left the cmd.exe open and the program execution did not resumed till I closed that window. There might be ways around it that will make this option less desirable...

Answer (score 2):

I'm with Glen and John, except I'd prefer to use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) instead. That way you have a process handle you can do something with. Examples might be [Kill IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714(VS.85).aspx) when you are done with it, or have a thread watching for IE to terminate ([WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx) with the process handle) so it could do something like restart it, or shut down your program too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
system("\"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore\" http://www.shail.com");
  Works perfectly..